# Change printer properties in excel macro

Tags: vba, excel, printing

Is there any way I can change printer properties to color rather than black and white in an Excel macro/Excel VBA? I would like to print in color from the macro but every time I exit excel it sets the color to black and white.  I would like for the macro to set the color back to color every time I run it.  This is the code I am using to print:

```
Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet3").PrintOut from:=1, To:=(i / 2) - 0.5
```

This prints every page effected by the macro but it does it in black and white.  I have already tried this but it didn't change anything:

```
Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet3").PageSetup.BlackAndWhite = False
```

If it isn't possible to do this in vba I would be fine with an API solution as well.

Comment: Record a macro and see what it does. This should be easy. Not sure of your statement syntax Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("DoNotDelete").PageSetup.BlackAndWhite = False

Comment: @Peekay I just tried recording it while I changed it from black and white to color (by clicking File>Print>Printer Properties>Color) and it came up with an empty macro.

Comment: I am surprised. Look at this. Seems to be useful. http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/684859-help-w-visual-basic-applications-open-dialog-box-select-color-printer-list-change-setup.html

Comment: @Peekay That was very helpful, however it still requires there to be a printer with color as it's default print settings.  The statement `PageSetup.BlackAndWhite = False` sets the page's default to color but not the printer defaults.  What I am looking for is to print color whether its default setting is color or black and white.  I know this is a tough topic as I have been looking into it for a couple days now, but I am coding this to distribute to a number of people at my work and I do not really want to walk everyone through changing the defaults in the control panel.

Comment: As much as I understand to get around the default settings on a system driver is more or less tricky. What you would need to do to change the default setting on a printer is to use Microsoft/Printer vendor APIs to get functionality to control the driver parameters. I might be totally wrong, but to me it seems that it's going to be a long night without a sleep to code a this functionality, and if a person is going to use some other printer with different Vendor drivers it'll fall flat again. [A good article about this](http://www.lessanvaezi.com/changing-printer-settings-using-the-windows-api/)

Comment: @SickDimension thanks for your help! I guess it's about time I learn API...

Comment: You can use WMI to tell if the printer is configured in black and white or colour - but although tantalisingly close, not to change it. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/aa394364%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @Tim.DeVries Can we just clarify why **`.PageSetup.BlackAndWhite = False`** does not work for you?

Comment: @mehow that still doesn't do it because the print settings are still at b&w instead of color but i need them to be color and i don't want to do that manually every time before i run the macro.

Comment: This seems relevant http://stackoverflow.com/a/18334730/2626313

Comment: @Tim.DeVries have you looked in your `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository` ? you may be able to find an *.ini with the settings for the printer. You may be able to programmatically open it an modify the `xColor= Color` or something similar

Comment: Printer drivers store their settings in binary in the Windows registry under the USER path. The binary differs by printer driver. If this is only for one printer, you can set the printer to colour, export the registry key for that printer, set it to black and white, and export that. Then it is simply a matter of running reg.exe using VBA Shell with the exported .reg file to either colour or black and white.

Answer (score 7):

Rather than using:

```
Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet3").PrintOut from:=1, To:=(i / 2) - 0.5
```

You could just use:

```
Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet3").PrintOut
```

and you can skip:

```
Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("DoNotDelete").PageSetup.BlackAndWhite = False
```

Because it only changes the worksheet settings, not the print settings.

But as far as printing in color goes you are probably best off just creating a shortcut the same printer twice in the `control panel` and set one to default color and another to default black and white.  This way you can specify color or black/white just by which printer you choose.

Comment: how does this answer the colour/black and white question?

Comment: @brettdj His last paragraph is a suggestion how to solve that problem (use two printers pointing to the same machine with different settings). those printers can also be created and deleted programatically, but you will need Admin privileges for that.